# Reference for numerically non-negative polynomials for nef vector bundles

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, vector-bundles, intersection-theory

Let $K$ be a field. A polynomial $F \in \mathbb{Q}[X_1, \dots, X_r]$ which is weighted homogeneous of degree $n$ with respect to the grading $\deg(X_k) = k$ is called *numerically non-negative for nef vector bundles* if for every $n$-dimensional projective $K$-variety $X$ and every nef vector bundle $E$ of rank $r$ on $X$ we have $\int_X F(c_1(E), \dots, c_r(E)) \ge 0$. According to Example 8.3.10 in Lazarsfeld's book *Positivity in Algebraic Geometry II* a polynomial is numerically non-negative for nef vector bundles if and only if it is a non-negative linear combination of the Schur polynomials. However Lazarsfeld only works over the complex ground field.

**Question:** Is there a citeable reference where the fact stated above is stated (and proved) over an arbitrary ground field?

Note that the paper *Positive Polynomials for Ample Vector Bundles* by Fulton and Lazarsfeld allows an arbitrary ground field, but there only positive polyomials are considered which have a similar description.

Comment: I don't think the proof depends much on the ground field.  See Fulton's followup paper, "Positive polynomials for filtered ample vector bundles" (Amer J Math, 1995), which takes the setting to be over a general field, and also Demailly-Peternell-Schneider (J. Alg. Geom, 1994), which proves the result you want over C.

Comment: @DaveAnderson Thank you for your comment! Unfortunately, also in Fulton's paper about filtered vector bundles, at least the statement of Theorem' about nef vector bundles refers to the complex ground field (it refers to compact Kähler manifolds). Maybe the proof (in the case of a projective variety) works over an arbitrary ground field, I didn't have time to properly check this yet.

Comment: But even if the proof is alright, it would be nice, to just have the statement over an arbitrary ground field somewhere…